# Ayuda con comunicación serial Arduino

Tags: java, arduino

Buenas tardes,
Tengo un problema con arduino y la comunicación serial entre Java y Arduino.
Estoy haciendo un "sistema de refrigeración" que funcione como si fuese un aire acondicionado. Una caja que puedas meter la temperatura y los botones encender y apagar. Lo tengo ya casi implementado, sólo me falta porque no consigo que me lo haga, al meter el valor de la temperatura en java, lo metemos en un string y comprobamos en java que sea numérico de cara a pasarlo al arduino mediante un arduino.send(string con el valor); 
También tiene un sensor de presencia, el sistema funciona si en vez de pasar la variable desde java le asigno una variable en Arduino.
El problema es que la variable de arduino no coge el valor que le paso.
Adjunto el código de arduino para ver si detectáis que estoy haciendo mal.

```
int temperatura = 0; //variable para la temperatura
int tempPuente;
int fan = 8; //pin digital dodne conectar el ventildor
int pir = 2;  // pin 2 va a la señal del sensor de movimiento
int pir_lectura;
String input;

void setup(){
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(fan,OUTPUT);//configuracion del pin 8
  pinMode(pir, INPUT);  // Configurar pir como entrada o INPUT  
  Serial.begin(9600);


}

void funcionamiento(){
  Serial.print("La temperatura String: ");
  Serial.println(input);
  Serial.print("La temperatura indicada es: ");
  Serial.println(tempPuente);

  while(Serial.available()>0){
    Serial.print("Temperatura puente: ");
    Serial.println(tempPuente);
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    //Calcula la temperatura usando como referencia 5v
    temperatura = (int) (5.0 * analogRead(0)*100.0)/1023.0;
    Serial.println(temperatura); //escribe la temperatura en el serial
    delay (500); //espera 5 segundos para la siguiente medicion
    pir_lectura = digitalRead(pir);
    if(temperatura>tempPuente){
      Serial.println("Temperatura alta");
      if (pir_lectura == HIGH) {
        digitalWrite(fan, LOW);
        Serial.println("Hay movimiento");
      }
      else 
      {
        digitalWrite(fan, HIGH);
        Serial.println("No hay movimiento");
      }
    }
    else
    {
      digitalWrite(fan, HIGH);
      Serial.println("Temperatura baja");
    }  
  }
}

void loop(){
 input = Serial.read();
 tempPuente = input.toInt();
 if(Serial.available()>0){
    funcionamiento();
 }
```

}

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero: Serial.read() te devuelve un caracter, no toda la linea, con lo cual tienes definir un caracter como el caracter de entrada que envia la terminal, y establecer que si el carcter es un salto de linea, que quiere decir que la terminal envia un "\n", proceses los datos que ha enviado, pero hasta que no reciba un salto de linea tienes que ir almacenando esos caracteres en un String por ejemplo.

Te dejo el codigo modificado, lo he probado y recibe los datos que la terminal le envia.

```
  int temperatura = 0; //variable para la temperatura
  int tempPuente;
  int fan = 8; //pin digital dodne conectar el ventildor
  int pir = 2;  // pin 2 va a la señal del sensor de movimiento
  int pir_lectura;
  String input;

  void setup(){
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(fan,OUTPUT);//configuracion del pin 8
  pinMode(pir, INPUT);  // Configurar pir como entrada o INPUT  
  Serial.begin(9600);


}

void funcionamiento(){
  Serial.print("La temperatura String: ");
  Serial.println(input);
  Serial.print("La temperatura indicada es: ");
  Serial.println(tempPuente);

  while(Serial.available()>0){
    Serial.print("Temperatura puente: ");
    Serial.println(tempPuente);
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    //Calcula la temperatura usando como referencia 5v
    temperatura = (int) (5.0 * analogRead(0)*100.0)/1023.0;
    Serial.println(temperatura); //escribe la temperatura en el serial
    delay (500); //espera 5 segundos para la siguiente medicion
    pir_lectura = digitalRead(pir);
    if(temperatura>tempPuente){
      Serial.println("Temperatura alta");
      if (pir_lectura == HIGH) {
       digitalWrite(fan, LOW);
       Serial.println("Hay movimiento");
      }
      else 
      {
        digitalWrite(fan, HIGH);
        Serial.println("No hay movimiento");
      }
    }
    else
    {
      digitalWrite(fan, HIGH);
      Serial.println("Temperatura baja");
    }  
  }
}

void loop(){
  if(Serial.available()){
    char caracterEntrada = Serial.read();
    if(caracterEntrada != '\n'){
   // Aqui el caracter no es una nueva linea, con lo cual lo  introducimos en el String
      input += caracterEntrada; 
     } else {
       // Aqui el serial nos indica que es un salto de linea, con lo cual tenemos todos los datos asi que podemos proceder a procesarlos
      tempPuente = input.toInt();
      funcionamiento();
      input = ""; 
    }

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con este código. Básicamente debes de leer caracter por caracter, pero dale tiempo al arduino para que procese.

```
  while(Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    command = ((byte)Serial.read());
    if(command == '\n')
    {
      break;
    }
    else
    {
      string += command;
    }
    delay(20);   
  }
if ((string.toInt()>=0)&&(string.toInt()<=255))
{
input = Serial.read();
tempPuente = input.toInt();
funcionamiento();
}
```

Comment: Es básicamente leer caracter por caracter, pero darle tiempo al arduino para que procese.