# Escribir dos lineas en serial al mismo tiempo

Tags: c#, arduino, serialport

Estoy haciendo un monitor de CPU y RAM con arduino, para que lo escriba en un LCD.

El problema es que solo me escribe una linea, cuando yo quiero que escriba la CPU arriba y la RAM abajo:

CPU: xx.xxx

RAM: xx.xxx

Ya probe usando Serial.NewLine, \n en distinas posiciones e intercambiar el Serial.Write y Serial.WriteLine

**Codigo C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
//using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices;

namespace Performance_Counter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        String COMPort = "COM5";
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                serialPort1.PortName = COMPort;
                serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
                serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
                serialPort1.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), "One");
                serialPort1.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), "None");

                serialPort1.Open();
                progressBar1.Value = 100;
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            lblCOMPort.Text = COMPort;  //Label que marca el puerto usado

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string CPUUsage = "CPU:" + performanceCounterCPU.NextValue();
            string RAMUsage = "RAM:" + performanceCounterRAM.NextValue();

            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.WriteLine(CPUUsage + "         ");
                serialPort1.WriteLine(RAMUsage + "         ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**performanceCounterCPU**

CategoryName: Procesador

CounterName: % de tiempo de procesador

InstanceName: _Total

**performanceCounterRAM**

CategoryName: Memory

CounterName: % Committed Bytes in use

InstanceName:

**Codigo Arduino**

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available()) {
    delay(100);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    while (Serial.available() > 0) {
      lcd.write(Serial.read());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en el código siempre despliegas en la posición (0,0). Lo correcto sería leer la línea, revisar si comienza con "RAM" o "CPU", y según eso hacer el `lcd.setCursor()` correspondiente.

Te simplificarías la vida si envias ambos valores en una misma línea, separados por un blanco, eliminado las leyendas.

De todos modos, el problema es que supones que `Serial.read()` te va a devolver **toda** la línea. Esto no es asi; `Serial.read()` te devuelve sólo un caracter a la vez., con los que tienes que armar la línea antes de procesarla para extraer los valores.

Mira la [respuesta de José Luis](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/78230/ayuda-con-comunicaci%C3%B3n-serial-arduino) a una pregunta similar.